# Output from recursive function R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a simple recursive function in R which each time will return just a single number. I want to store these in a column basically. So initially I'm declaring something like
    `relevant=c(rep(0,16))`
then if it satisfies some criteria I want to change the corresponding values of 
relevant[j] to 1.
    `if(something==1){`
      `relevant[j]=1`
    }

But then when I call relevant outside the function all the values are 0. The criteria is definitely being satisfied, but it just doesn't seem to change the values!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: please add your "simple enough recursive function" and the desired output (you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you modify your question so it is easier for us to answer it)

Comment: Tried to clarify a bit, but if still not clear let me know

Comment: does any of the answers below help you ? if no, can you explain why? It is still unclear to me what you exactly want to do: with the further explanation, I don't see where you need a recursive function (or even a function). Please add your actual function and what you're expecting as output

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "simple enough recursive function" that will return a vector of numbers, each one being calculated inside the function:

```
serf <- function(x){
            if (length(x)==5) {
              return(x)
            } else {
               x <- c(x, x[length(x)]+1) ; serf(x)
            }
        }


serf(1)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is that what you had in mind ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to do, but I interpret it as having a recursive function that returns a single value and wanting as well to accumulate the results of the recursive calls as a side effect.

Here's an example based on computation of Fibonacci numbers that solves this problem using a closure. A couple of caveats: (1) This is a terribly inefficient way to compute Fibonacci numbers. (2) Building up an object like `values` element-wise is very inefficient in R; if you know the length of the result in advance, it's much better to initialize the object to that length and then index into it.

```
> makefib <- function(){
+   values <- vector("numeric")
+   function(n){
+     if (n == 0) return(values)
+     res <- if (n < 3) 1 else Recall(n - 1) + Recall(n - 2)
+     values[length(values) + 1] <<- res
+     res
+   }
+ }   

> fib <- makefib()
> fib(6)
 [1] 8
> fib(0)
 [1] 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 5 1 1 2 1 3 8
```

I hope this helps.